# Issue while reloading Jqgrid with Scroll - Duplicate row data and missing last page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jqgrid

Please refer my code below, which I am using to load data from database. Code works fine as far as it loads data for the 1st time. Each record and each page loads perfectly.

Now If i call a Reload function it creates issues.

1. Sometime it loads duplicate rows (say if my jason returning 20 rows, grid will show 40)
2. I loose the last page of the records in grid.

---

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "http://localhost/myapp/myfile.php",
            datatype: "json",                
            mtype:"POST",
            postData:{folder: 'INBOX' },
            jsonReader: 
            {
                root: "rows",
                page: "currpage",
                total: "totalpages",
                records: "totalrecords",
                id: "0",
                cell:"",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            colNames: ['Id','Message'],
            colModel: [ 
                        { name: 'messageid', index: 'messageid', hidden: true, search:false},
                        { name: 'message', index: 'message', search:false},
                      ],
            rowNum: 10,
            scroll: 1,
            prmNames:{npage:1},
            autowidth: true,
            height: 470,
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows:true,                
            caption: "",
            pager: "#plist",
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

    function reload_list()
    {
        $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
```

---

Please Note the following information

Framework I'm using is **Codeigniter** with JqGrid Version **jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1**.

Files I have included in my code are

1. css/ui.jqgrid.css
2. js/grid.locale-en.js
3. js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js
4. plugins/grid.postext.js
5. src/jqModal.js
6. src/jqDnR.js

---

DEMO: http://www.trimantra.com/demo/appointmentsystem/grid.php

Please Let me know How I can resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really required to use combination of `scroll: 1` and `loadonce: true`? I find the implementation of virtual scrolling in jqGrid not good enough and don't recommend to use it. Moreover the code of `jqModal.js` and `jqDnR.js` already included in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You should remove `http://localhost` prefix from the `url`.

Comment: I have removed  **loadonce: true** and Both Files **jqModal.js** and **jqDnR.js** from my code. Now I'm getting duplicate records while loading for the 1st time

Comment: I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Developer Tools of Chrome or IE to catch HTTP traffic between the server and the client. It will be send one or two requests to the server. You can append JSON from the both responses to the text of your question.

Comment: If I remove **setGridParam({datatype:'json'})** from reload function, it loads result perfectly but it will stop making Ajax Calls. I want my code to make Ajax Call each time while executing reload function.

Comment: You current code don't shows in which situation you use `.trigger("reloadGrid")`. You just define `reload_list` function which will be never used. Moreover it's unclear which setting you *currently* use. Do you use `loadonce: true`? In the case reloading will be done *locally* and no request to the server will be send. Local reloading could be helpful to change the sort order, the page number and so on.

Comment: **(1)** **onSelectRow** I am Updating the status of the message and reloading the grid. **(2)** Yes I'm using loadonce: true, If I remove it, I instantly get duplicate records on grid.

Comment: You should hold one strategy in the solution. 1) the code which you posted don't contain any implementation of the `onSelectRow` callback. 2) You should not use `loadonce: true` and `scroll: 1` together. If you use `loadonce: true` you should include the **whole** data (not one page only) in the server response. I suppose it's not what you need. 3) It you have problem with duplicate records you should trace HTTP traffic and append your question with the JSON responses from the server.

Comment: I have just Updated a Demo URL. 3 possible Grids. What I want is 1 Grid with perfect Data loading + can make ajax call when reload the grid and maintain grid records (not to show duplicate rows.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your code:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

It's because of this that it is creating a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem with row duplication, but I could see a lot of other problems in your application.

I suppose that your main problem is because **you loads the data with the same ids** in all three grids. As the results you have id duplicates on the page. The most easy way to fix the problem will be the usage of `idPrefix` option of jqGrid.

Below you find the list of the most important problems which I found:

- You included incorrectly jQuery UI in your application. You don't included `images` subdirectory of the theme. So the application get "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" error on the loading of `http://www.trimantra.com/demo/appointmentsystem/lib/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/themes/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png`. You should include all `images` in your project.
- You don't use `idPrefix` option in the grids and *load the same data in three grids*. As the result all three grids will have `<tr>` elements with the same id. HTML don't allow id duplication. To fix the problem you can use for example `idPrefix: "a"`, `idPrefix: "b"`, `idPrefix: "c"` for the three grids. As the results the row having `messageid: "45"` will get `id="a45"` in the first grid, `id="b45"` and `id="c45"` in the last grid and you will have no id duplicates on the page.
- I see no sense in combination of `scroll: 1` and `loadonce: true`. If I understand what you need to do you should just remove  `scroll: 1` and `prmNames:{npage:1}` from all grids. The options are needed for virtual scrolling.
- You should add `gridview: true` option which will improve performance of grids in many times in case of large number of rows.
- The server response which produce the server currently not corresponds the jqGrid request. The request will contains `rows=10`, `page=1`, `sidx=toname`, `sord=asc`. The server returns **all 48 rows of data** and the data are **unsorted**. In any way you should insert sorting of data in your server code.
- You use `frozen:true` in all visible columns. I see no sense in the settings.
- If you don't need to display `'messageid'` column you can just *remove* the column definition from the `colModel` and use `jsonReader: {id: "messageid", repeatitems: false }`. As the results the will save place on the page (hidden columns still get place on the page).
- You should better transfer dates in locale independent format [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Additionally you should use `formatter: 'data'` to display the dates in the format like `05/16/2012 07:45 AM` which you use you can use `formatoptions: { newformat: "d/m/Y H:i A" }`. The main benefit will be correct sorting order of the column in case of usage `loadonce: true`.
- You should remove trailing commas from `colModel` definitions. The combination `},]` is an error in JavaScript. The error will be ignored in the most modern web browsers (but not in old like IE6). It's better to write error free code.

Comment: Thats a big one. Let me try one by one.

Comment: I do agree for most of the changes here. What I have just observed is about Height. can you please take a look at Demo link once again and process following steps. #1. Scroll down grid 1 completely. #2. Reload Grid 1  #3. Scroll down grid 1 again(you will see missing records). Repeat same steps for Grid 2. want to know why height is making such a difference?

Comment: @pinaldesai: Sorry, but the current version of [the demo](http://www.trimantra.com/demo/appointmentsystem/grid.php) have still the most errors which I described before. For example you have still id dupplicates because you use the same `url` in both grids and no `idPrefix`. For example the first `<tr>` element (the first row) in both grids has *the same* `id="45"`. It's really heavy error. Next jQuery UI still not full: the `ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png` can't be loaded. The server response still are wrong in case of usage `scroll: 1`, `height` value is wrong.

Comment: @pinaldesai: I wrote you many times that I don't recommend you to use virtual scrolling in case of 48 rows of data. You will have better results if you remove `scroll: 1`. I'm not developer of jqGrid. I can help you to use jqGrid. Moreover I wrote you that I don't like the implementation of virtual scrolling in jqGrid. So if you think that you found some bug in virtual which you should post it to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/) and not here.